# Обучение простой нейронной сети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

По примеру из видео на ютубе решил сделать первую нейросеть, чтобы на практике понять принципы обучения подобных нейросетей. Суть задачи проста - на входе 9 нейронов в каждый из которых попадает значение 0 или 1. Входные данные описывают собой 3х3 квадрат. На выходе 2 нейрона, один отвечает за присутствие вертикальной линии длинной 3 клетки в данном квадрате, другой за горизонтальную линию такой же длинны. В качестве набора для обучения даю либо 6, либо 21 подобных квадратов в каждом из которых есть хоть одна линия (вертикальная или горизонтальная). Спустя несколько часов или дней залипания я довел до разума алгоритм и разобрался с подбором коэффициентов, проанализировал лучшие результаты. График в целом очень похож на стандартные случаи обучения нейросетей, единственное возможно на входном массиве длинной 21 элемент бывают более длинные плато. Они также есть и на 6, но там оно, что логично не такое долгое по количеству итераций.
Веса обучаются нормально, значение среднеквадратичной ошибки сильно приближено к нулю (1/1000 после 5 тыс. итераций прогона массива). Количество нейронов в скрытых слоях - 4 и 3 в двух скрытых слоях. Пробовал изменять количество нейронов и лучших результатов не получал даже на большем количестве итераций.
Проблемы начинаются когда обученная нейросеть начинает работать с случайным набором данных. В пике значение среднеквадратичной ошибки не падает ниже 0.15, а угадывание ответов при 200 итерациях на случайных наборах данных не превышает 80%, то есть 320 правильных ответов против 80 неправильных (поскольку угадываются оба значения выходных нейронов - имеем х2 ответов).
Я понимаю что с учетом начального датасета это больше похоже на справедливый результат, поскольку нейросеть была обучена на работу с конкретным набором данных, тут же ей пихают абсолютно другие данные, которые она до этого не видела и соответственно определенные последствия обучения на изначальном датасете могут мешать в конечном результате. Однако распределение нулей и единиц в подобном массиве квадрата 3х3 имеет всего 512 различных вариантов. Соответственно нет никакого смысла в нейросети если я просто дам ей выучить все ответы, чтобы получить нужный мне результат.
Отсюда возникает вопрос от начинающего кодера: какие ухищрения и методы есть в машинном обучении чтобы улучшить подобный алгоритм и добиться лучших результатов обучения? Я слышал о распределении нейронов по группам, так например можно было бы связать входные нейроны с 6-ю нейронами в скрытом слое, каждый из которых будет отвечать за ту или иную линию. Вот только это все равно что дать готовый ответ на задачу, насколько я понимаю.
В следствии своей неопытности и поверхностного понимания работы нейросетей интересуюсь данной темой у более опытных специалистов.
Заранее спасибо.
[image: 2000 итераций на датасете из 6 входных массивов]

Comment: Что-то я из описания не понял. Вы подаёте обучающие данные, где вертикальная линия гарантирована в одном месте из трёх, а хотите получить хорошее качество на тестовом наборе данных, где вертикальная линия расположена на любом из трёх мест? Ну, нейросеть - не магия. Как она должна догадаться, что речь идёт о вертикальных линиях, если вы показали ей только одну линию? Либо я неправильно понял описание задачи, либо вы хотите чего-то странного. Нет, у меня есть рецепты от переобучения - вносить шум в картинку, но на таком малом количестве данных в любом случае будет сложно заниматься Big Data.

Comment: Не совсем так. Ни вертикальная ни горизонтальная линия не гарантированы, но изначальный датасет содержит квадраты в которых есть либо вертикальная, либо горизонтальная, либо обе сразу. Выходные нейроны как раз показывают существует данная линия или же нет. Но по сути при всем этом нейросеть действительно должна рассматривать каждую линию. В тестовом наборе показаны все случаи когда вертикальная и горизонтальные линии существуют. Возможно неточность появляется когда на вход подается квадрат с незакоченной линией из двух активных точек, ведь в обучающем наборе таких случаев нет.